# Dynamically add slug for products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We're adding a slug to the product's URL dynamically, like this:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_product_link', 1, 2 );
function custom_product_link( $post_link, $post ) {


    if ( $post->post_type == 'product') {

        //In this point, $post_link is, for example: https://domain.test/business/%vendor_slug%/product-demo/
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get($post->post_author);
        $shop_url = $vendor->get_shop_url();
        $pieces = explode("/", $shop_url);
        $post_link = str_replace("%vendor_slug%", $pieces[sizeof($pieces)-2], $post_link );
        //In this point, previous $post_link is: https://domain.test/business/daniel/product-demo/

    }

    return $post_link;

}
```

The URL https://domain.test/business/daniel/ is the store of the vendor ( dokan plugin ), and it's working ok, but when we go to the resultant URL -> https://domain.test/business/daniel/product-demo/ it's returning 404 error code, not found.

In WordPress permalink options, we set following:

[image]

We also tried adding:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_add_query_vars');
function custom_add_query_vars($qVars){
    $qVars[] = "vendor_slug";
    return $qVars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrites_init' );
function custom_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'product/([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=product&vendor_slug=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

But error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved by overriding product_cat rule, like following:

1. In WordPress permalink options, setting following:

/business/%product_cat%/

2. Updating the code like this:

   ```
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_product_link', 1, 2 );
    function custom_product_link( $post_link, $post ) {


    if ( $post->post_type == 'product') {

        //In this point, $post_link is, for example: https://domain.test/business/%product_cat%/product-demo/
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get($post->post_author);
        $shop_url = $vendor->get_shop_url();
        $pieces = explode("/", $shop_url);
        $post_link = str_replace("%product_cat%", $pieces[sizeof($pieces)-2], $post_link );
        //In this point, previous $post_link is: https://domain.test/business/daniel/product-demo/

    }

    return $post_link;

    }
   ```
3. We can remove the code related to add_filter...query_vars, and also the code related to add_action...init

Summary, we overrided product_cat rule, adding the shop slug instead.